# Multithreading using synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning multithreading. I have a following code:

```
public class Intro {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Intro().doCounter();
    }

    private int counter = 0;

    synchronized void increment() {
        counter++;
    }


    private void doCounter() {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
                    increment();
                }
                System.out.println("first: " + counter);
            }
        });

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
                    increment();
                }
                System.out.println("second: " + counter);
            }
        });

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();


    }
}

Output (can differ):
first: 1741739
second: 2000000
```

The code has two threads. One thread increment the counter million times, while the second wait. Then the second increment it million times as well. I understand why the second thread get 2 million, but didn't get why the first thread get 1741739. Why it isn't 1 million for the first thread? I think it had to stop at 1 million. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: Why do you think it should be 1M for the first thread? The only thing `synchronized` here is the `increment()` method.

Comment: @Savior Because it increments 1M times and stops.

Comment: Do you, for some reason, think thread 2 only starts after thread 1 has finished?

Comment: @Savior Yes. It isn't?

Comment: No, that's what I meant by _why do you think so?_ You started both threads, there's nothing else preventing thread 2 from doing its thing.

Comment: Both threads are running at the same time.  That's the whole point of multithreading.  If you run it enough times, you could actually end up with thread1 reaching 2M before thread2 gets there.  It just doesn't happen very often because thread1 is started just before thread2, so it gets a head start.  Even weirder, if you run it lots of times, you might notice sometimes neither thread gets to 2M.  This is because `counter` is not volatile, so its value isn't necessarily the same on both threads.  You could end up with threads incrementing a stale value of `counter`.

Comment: @Savior I think I get it. The synchronized prevents it. But when first thread finished and the second enters, it works so quick that the first is not able to print 1m at a time and it just print some increments from second thread as well.

Comment: @charlie `println` is `synchronized` as well, so `counter` will be read as 2M by the final thread.

Comment: @Savior Good point, one thread will always display as 2M, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you have two problems.

- You need to understand that threading execution is not predictable. Each thread gets scheduled for a certain amount of time on a CPU core as decided by the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) and the [OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system). How often each thread gets scheduled, and for how long, depends on conditions at runtime. So their work can be interleaved, with no guarantee as to which thread will run when, or finish first/last.
- Your code is accessing a resource, a member field variable `counter` across threads without protection. This is not thread-safe. Due to modern CPU architecture and the Java Memory Model, your two threads might see two different states of that single variable. For example, each of two cores running your two threads might each have a different copy of the variable in its cache.

One solution is to use `AtomicInteger` as your `counter` variable rather than `int`. An `AtomicInteger` is thread-safe, protecting access to its contained `int` value. By using `AtomicInteger`, you no longer need your synchronized `increment` method.

Here is some example code for that.

An `Incrementor` class that contains our `AtomicInteger` variable named `count` as a member field. The class carries nested class `IncrementingTask` that is a `Runnable` with a `run` method to be executed on background threads, incrementing our `count` var a million times. The class has a `demo` method for starting any number of threads, each thread running an instance of `IncrementingTask` to increment the million times.

```java
package work.basil.threading;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Incrementor
{
    // Member fields.
    final private AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger( 0 );

    public void demo ( )
    {
        int threadsLimit = 2;
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( threadsLimit );
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < threadsLimit ; i++ )
        {
            executorService.submit( new IncrementingTask() );
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        try { executorService.awaitTermination( 1 , TimeUnit.HOURS ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        // At this point, the tasks are all done/canceled/failed.
        System.out.println( "RESULTS: count is at: " + this.count.get() );
    }

    // Runnable task.
    class IncrementingTask implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run ( )
        {
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < 1_000_000 ; i++ )
            {
                int incrementedCount = count.incrementAndGet();
                if ( i % 100_000 == 0 )
                {
                    System.out.println( "Thread # " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " incremented count to: " + incrementedCount + " at " + Instant.now() );
                }
            }
            System.out.println( "Thread # " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " is done incrementing. " + Instant.now() );
        }
    }
}
```

A class to run this.

```java
package work.basil.threading;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        Incrementor incrementor = new Incrementor();
        incrementor.demo();
    }
}
```

When run.

```
Thread # 15 incremented count to: 2 at 2021-03-29T00:04:37.099350Z
Thread # 14 incremented count to: 1 at 2021-03-29T00:04:37.099281Z
Thread # 14 incremented count to: 200002 at 2021-03-29T00:04:37.155680Z
Thread # 15 incremented count to: 198267 at 2021-03-29T00:04:37.155659Z
Thread # 15 incremented count to: 387108 at 2021-03-29T00:04:37.165850Z
Thread # 14 incremented count to: 400002 at 2021-03-29T00:04:37.165894Z
Thread # 15 incremented count to: 552150 at 2021-03-29T00:04:37.168378Z
Thread # 14 incremented count to: 631000 at 2021-03-29T00:04:37.169329Z
Thread # 15 incremented count to: 753457 at 2021-03-29T00:04:37.170931Z
Thread # 14 incremented count to: 840455 at 2021-03-29T00:04:37.171943Z
Thread # 15 incremented count to: 942263 at 2021-03-29T00:04:37.173276Z
Thread # 14 incremented count to: 1049089 at 2021-03-29T00:04:37.174559Z
Thread # 15 incremented count to: 1135900 at 2021-03-29T00:04:37.175726Z
Thread # 14 incremented count to: 1240800 at 2021-03-29T00:04:37.177092Z
Thread # 15 incremented count to: 1308191 at 2021-03-29T00:04:37.177678Z
Thread # 15 incremented count to: 1439696 at 2021-03-29T00:04:37.179523Z
Thread # 15 incremented count to: 1595283 at 2021-03-29T00:04:37.180795Z
Thread # 14 incremented count to: 1604140 at 2021-03-29T00:04:37.181720Z
Thread # 14 incremented count to: 1800001 at 2021-03-29T00:04:37.183231Z
Thread # 14 incremented count to: 1900001 at 2021-03-29T00:04:37.184697Z
Thread # 15 is done incrementing. 2021-03-29T00:04:37.182735Z
Thread # 14 is done incrementing. 2021-03-29T00:04:37.188265Z
RESULTS: count is at: 2000000
```

Notice that every time we run this, we always get to exactly 2,000,000 million total. Also notice that every time you run this, the list of which thread ran when will vary, as will the count at each time the thread reports to us on the console.

### Console lies

Notice the counts look crazy. The first two lines report a count of `2` and then `1` rather than one then two. Same with the third and fourth lines, apparently backwards.

Look more closely to examine the microseconds of the timestamps. Those timestamps are *not* in chronological order.

Lesson learned: The `System.out.println` calls do not present on the console in chronological order. So never rely on such console output to give you a true picture of what happened when.

Always include a timestamp such as `Instant.now()` or `System.nanoTime()`. If you want to see messages in order, collect them in a thread-safe ordered collection such as `Collections.synchronizedList​( new ArrayList< String >() )`.

---

Alternatively, if you wanted to keep your `int` variable and synchronized  `increment` method rather than use `AtomicInteger` you must protect access to the `counter` variable in a thread-safe manner. Marking the variable as `volatile` would help. You can search Stack Overflow to learn more on this.